# Is there a way to sequentially execute XSL transformations in one stylesheet?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I've already found some information in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237531/is-there-a-technique-to-combine-a-pipeline-of-xsl-transformations-into-a-single) thread about the topic. But I'm not convinced that this will solve my problem easily.

**The issue:**
I have multiple transformations, that use XSLT 1.0.
The transformations do correct (make invalid XML valid), modify and join three different XML sources. Furthermore, there are some calculations done on the resulting XML nodes.

I'm pretty sure, that I could reduce some of the code, but for the moment the 7 stylesheets produce "human understandable" XML files with good results.

The process is based in Excel, where I call those stylesheets via VBA. This works but feels pretty much clumsy.

What I'm looking for is a solution, that executes those stylesheets in sequence. `<xsl:include>` and `<xsl:import>` aren't working for this, as there are multiple manipulations on some nodes involved and I need to keep the code at least somewhat readable.

**In short:**
I'm searching for something like this, but in respect to colliding templates in the stylesheets:

```
<xsl:include href="$external"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="document($path)"/>
```

**Some examples regarding the comments:**
*1. making invalid XML valid*
There are some tags in the XML source, that are not set correctly, like the following example shows.

```
<Elements_12 NODE="embedded object" TYPE="130">
  <ExpProps_0 NODE="embedded object">
    <Name>Text.Text</Name>
    <ExpPropValue>&lt;Text&gt;@TEMPLATE_pic_data_AlarmHistory_PrintReport&lt;/Text&gt;</ExpPropValue>
  </ExpProps_0>
</Elements_12>
```

I'm correcting this by some short code snippets:

```
<xsl:template match="text()[starts-with(.,'&lt;Text&gt;')]">
  <Text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '&lt;Text&gt;'), '&lt;/Text&gt;')"/>
  </Text>
</xsl:template>
```

*2. The calls in VBA:*

```
' LOAD XML
xmlDoc.async = False
xmlDoc.Load strFileToOpen

' LOAD XSL
xslDoc.async = False
xslDoc.Load "element_stuff.xsl"

' TRANSFORM
xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
newDoc.Save ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Output.xml"

' LOAD XML
xmlDoc.async = False
xmlDoc.Load ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Output.xml"

' LOAD XSL
xslDoc.async = False
xslDoc.Load "fetch_stuff.xsl"

' TRANSFORM
xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
newDoc.Save ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Output.xml"
```

Comment: The referenced post has the possible approaches, I don't think there is anything easier or more straightforward. There is certainly no way to use a variable in `xsl:include href`. As for doing `<xsl:apply-templates select="document($path)"/>`, that is possible if you want to load or process secondary input documents.

Comment: So, if this is the only way, maybe I'm better off keeping the stuff in VBA then. It's just ugly and I had preferred some elegant way in xsl (as in keep xsl doing xsl stuff and VBA doing VBA stuff).

Comment: How are you doing the XSLT transformation in VBA? Are you aware that MSXML has a `transformNodeToObject` method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766561(v=vs.85).aspx) that allows DOM to DOM transformation instead of having to use strings or intermediary files?

Comment: Actually I'm using that exact method in VBA: `xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc`

Comment: Run your process at application layer like Excel VBA. Show us this *clumsy* effort. Recall XSLT is a special-purpose language like SQL meant to do one thing and not many things like filesystem iteration and calls. By the way this is a very interesting note you made --*make invalid XML valid*-- as no compliant DOM API library like MSXML could even read in invalid markup files. You must be running text file I/O handling outside XSLT.

Comment: @Parfait, I've updated the original post with some VBA code. It just _feels_ clumsy to execute all the stylesheets in sequence there.

Comment: That is valid XML. It may be *invalid* per your needs. You can use a loop in VBA for DRY-er code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a VBA loop to iterate through each XSLT script, conditionally changing first call:

```vb
Public Sub RunXSLs()
    Dim var As Variant
    Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument, xslDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument, newDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument

    For Each var In Array("1.xsl", "2.xsl", "3.xsl", "4.xsl", "5.xsl", "6.xsl", "7.xsl")
        Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument: Set xslDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument: Set newDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument

        ' LOAD XML
        xmlDoc.async = False
        If var = "1.xsl" Then
            xmlDoc.Load ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Input.xml"
        Else
            xmlDoc.Load ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Output.xml"
        End If

        ' LOAD XSL
        xslDoc.async = False
        xslDoc.Load ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & var

        ' TRANSFORM
        xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
        newDoc.Save ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Output.xml"

        Set xmlDoc = Nothing: Set xslDoc = Nothing: Set newDoc = Nothing
    Next var

End Sub
```

Comment: This is not actually solving the thing in xsl, but this is a far more sleek approach in VBA than I currently have. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why are `<xsl:include>` and `<xsl:import>` not working? As far as we can tell from your question they are the most obvious solution.

**What will work**

The first script:

```
<xsl:import href="two.xslt"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <text>one</text>
    <xsl:call-template name="seq2"/>
</xsl:template>
```

the second script:

```
<xsl:import href="three.xslt"/>
<xsl:template name="seq2">
    <text>two</text>
    <xsl:call-template name="seq3"/>
</xsl:template>
```

the last script:

```
<xsl:template name="seq3">
    <text>three</text>
</xsl:template>
```

**What will never work**

```
<xsl:include href="$external"/>
```

XSLT, like most (if not all) programming languages have imports resolved before any code gets executed. Trying to pass a variable is impossible because that variable does not exist when your compiler is looking for which document to import. It will therefore take the literal path to be "$external". This could be the source of your problems and may be worth looking into.

Comment: The problem is, that just like in the example I've added to my original post, one sheet creates valid nodes in a first pass, then work with said nodes. Another script is replacing placeholder nodes with the actual content from another file. A third is then doing calculations across the tree branch, where said corrected and replaced nodes are embedded in. And some more. This is why import (at least to my sparse knowledge) won't do the job here.

Comment: For what you're looking for there really isn't an alternative too `<xsl:include>` and `<xsl:import>`. There shouldn't be a reason why they wont work for stringing all transformations into a single call. I would guess you are getting tripped up with the all important context. It can be hard to get your head around where you are in your XSLT - especially the more complex your code gets (I suspect multiple inputs could be to blame here).

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that even if I would rework my transformations, there would still be 2 or even 3 of them left, but doing so would already be taking a lot of effort. After all I'm dumbing down 65mb of data to roughly 130kb with poorly exported XML from some SDK.
I've worked with includes and imports in the past already - so it's not that I'm not aware of their capabilities - I was just thinking, there might be some more trivial way to accomplish my task in xsl.